# adding key:value from dictionary to sqlite3 db and retrieving them back

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am saving sequences with different ids associated with them as two column in sqlite3 DB where sequence is a column and ids_string are another column. I have problem with retrieving from the database

The dictionary is created as uniqe_sequence = [list of ids]
the sequence is a string of roughly 7000 characters or less and the list of ids could be up to 1 million characters

```
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
import time
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Sausql_012419.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("create table Sau (sequence text, list_of_ids text)")
for record in sequences_dict_d:
    c.execute("insert into Sau values (?,?)", (record,'._/'.join(sequences_dict_d[record])))
conn.commit()
c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Saureus_panproteome")
sql_count = c.fetchall()
print("saved sql database of {} proteins in --- {:.3f} seconds ---".format(sql_count[0][0],time.time() - start_time))
c.close()
conn.close()
#retrieval exact sequence match
for record in SeqIO.parse(queryfile, _format):
   conn = sqlite3.connect('Sausql_012419.db')
   c = conn.cursor()
   c.execute('select list_of_ids from Sau where sequence = str(record.seq)')
   print(c.fetchall()) # or do something with the list_of_ids
```